# Can I lock down the Firebase Realtime DB to just my application?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, backendless

Is it possible to store data on a realtime firebase with the understanding that it will not be accessible to an outside user. So that the user won't be able to read this data, only my application will be able to read it (I expected this using some API key, but that's not what Firebase does).

Alternatively, if this is not possible and I think this is correct, can anyone advise me what backendless solution would be best to use? The one that offers this functionality?

Comment: Firebase is an excellent BaaS solution. the config passed to the app is what authenticates your app as the admin.

Comment: This used to not be possible, but nowadays you can restrict access through Firebase App Check.